# Samsung A42 5g, when i try to open an APK file it says i need to sign in to save file, where do i sign in?

Tags: samsung, apk, mobile-data, downloading, signature-error

I am trying to download an APK file, when I try to open it I get a message at the end to say I need to sign in before I can save the file, where do I sign in?

Comment: What browser are you using? What is the exact message? Could you post a screenshot of it?

Comment: Are you sure the message is "sign in" and not "signed" (the APK has to be signed otherwise installation is not possible).